Time dependent mass terms in field theory
In my research on Q-balls (a certain type of non-topological soliton) in cosmological backgrounds, I have obtained an equation that is nearly usable, except for one caveat. It would require me to postulate that the mass terms appearing in the potential $$U ( \phi^* \phi) = m^2 |\phi|^2 - \beta |\phi|^4 + \frac{\xi}{m^2} |\phi|^6$$ have a dependence on time in the form of $m(t) = \frac{m}{a(t)}$ where $a$ is the scale factor for an FLRW spacetime. Is it possible to obtain such a result through effective field theory, or some other means, in such a way that this is a physically realistic situation to be in?

This kind of thing comes up a lot in cosmology, and can be completely fine.
One caveat to be aware of: if the time dependent mass for $\phi$ arose as a coupling due to another field $\chi$, then you should check that the backreaction of $\phi$ on $\chi$ is small. For example, if you started with an interaction like $\frac{1}{2}g \phi^2 \chi^2$ (where $g$ is a coupling constant, and we perturb $\chi$ around some background solution $\chi=\bar{\chi(t)} + \delta \chi$, and assume $\phi$ has zero vev, then to leading order in perturbations the interaction would become $\frac{1}{2} g \bar{\chi}^2 \phi^2$, which has a time-dependent effective mass $m_{\rm eff}=\sqrt{g} \bar{\chi}$. Then, you should check that $\phi$ or $\delta \chi$ never becomes so large that the perturbative expansion around this background breaks down.
In terms of how to think of the effective mass, there are different cases.

If $|\dot{m}_{\rm eff}/m_{\rm eff}^2| \ll 1$, then we can treat the system using the adiabatic approximation. The effective mass is changing slowly compared to the timescale of low-frequency oscillations in $\phi$ induced by the effective mass ($\sim e^{i m_{\rm eff} t}$ for modes with $k \ll m_{\rm eff}$). In this limit, we can treat $\phi$ as being a field with a mass that depends on time.

If $m_{\rm eff}$ starts from a constant value, and approaches another constant value, and the adiabatic approximation does not hold, then you can interpret the process that occurs in terms of particle creation, because the time dependent mass term will cause the initial vacuum state to be different from the final vacuum state, leading to a non-trivial Bogoliubov transformation between the two vacua, which will generically result in particle creation. You can read more about this in (for example) the classic book by Birrell and Davies.

If $m_{\rm eff}^2$ oscillates sinusoidally, and you can ignore the $\phi^6$ term, then the equations of motion for $\phi$ are actually the Matthieu equation, which has a solution in terms of special functions known as Matthiew functions.



Thank you so much, this is immensely helpful. I appreciate the info on how the mass can arise, which may be helpful for future research. One last thing, if you could point me to some resources which discuss this/make use of it? It will be helpful for citations

@DanielWaters I think Birrell and Davies is well worth reading (especially the part on particle creation in a time dependent background). A key word if you want to search for other sources is "Bogoliubov transformation" -- you will find sources from both high energy and condensed matter physics points of view. In terms of how a coupling can lead to an effective mass, maybe read up on the Higgs mechanism. Any quantum mechanics book should talk about the adiabatic approximation for time dependent potentials.
